# Do I need the IV, Ciphertext, and MAC to decrypt a message? Are any of these optional?

Tags: private-key, cryptography, public-key

This it the encrypted message:
{
iv: '06ec88010977a8867a8851771b0558bd',
ephemPublicKey: '04d01f7f4cd5c9c54c959c99cfe052e5f52107a2e52c255af6d3d8fba3ae7f226760521ca11fbac30ef69de7a053a25976ebe8ade80243df710355d5c602f3bc6b',
ciphertext: '9e6f105156dabb57045c85d44649100e7e0c468a5b073b25fba84f95b188b624',
mac: '389b30af1452287fc965b2e5843f77a6193191d7c29b50664b95e2ad5abba107'
}

Do I need all of these to decrypt the message? In other words, would I have to store all of this information in order to decrypt it using the private key?

Comment: I have use eth-crypto library here. https://github.com/pubkey/eth-crypto

Comment: Do I need the ephemPublicKey as well?